# Replace specific letter from a word with input field

Tags: javascript, replace

```
const startButton= document.getElementById("startButton");
const resultButton = document.getElementById("resultButton");
const word1Element = document.getElementById("word1");
const word2Element = document.getElementById("word2");
const word3Element = document.getElementById("word3");
const word4Element = document.getElementById("word4");
const input1Element = document.getElementById("inputOne");
const input2Element = document.getElementById("inputTwo");
const input3Element = document.getElementById("inputThree");
const input4Element = document.getElementById("inputFour");
const countElement = document.getElementById("counter");
const modalInstructionsElement = document.getElementById("instructions");
const modalResultElement = document.getElementById("result");
const modalInstructionsCloseElement = document.getElementById("instructionsClose");
const modalResultCloseElement = document.getElementById("resultClose");




let result;
function randomWords () {
    word1Element.style.display = "block";
    word2Element.style.display = "block";
    word3Element.style.display = "block";
    word4Element.style.display = "block";
const words = [
    "kółko", "muzyka", "odór", "kukułka", "lupa", "buk", "półka", "kufel", "kultura", "chór",
    "muzeum", "rura", "kukułka", "róg", "lufa", "łuk", "łosoś", "kurtka", "budynek",
     "kukułka", "suknia", "ucho", "gorąco", "bułka", "szukanie", "podróż", "góra", "usta",
      "bukiet", "klucz", "łuk", "okrągły", "ludzie", "bułka", "kruk", "król", "żuraw", "kubek",
       "bukiet", "mówić", "płótno", "ludność", "kuracja", "kutia", "ubranie", "ukośny", "bukiet",
        "bruk", "kultura", "ruch", "buda", "kurczak", "dusza", "łuk", "kupować", "trudność", "brud",
         "skurczybyk", "słońce", "lód", "kupa", "lukier", "brud", "kusza", "tłum", "kufel", "duma", 
         "kupa", "pukanie", "kuracja", "burza", "kurtka", "smród", "bułka", "mur", "kultura", "buzia",
          "kurczak", "kąt", "żurawina", "łuk", "kula", "ukośny", "bukiet", "turysta", "urodziny", 
          "kufel", "buzia", "młodzież", "kuferek", "bujny", "ucieczka", "kuracja", "kutia", "rzut", 
          "bukiet", "wulkan", "kucyk", "uśmiech"
];
let wordOne = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
let inputOne = wordOne
.replace("ó", " ")
.replace("u", " ");
let wordTwo = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
let inputTwo = wordTwo
.replace("ó", " ")
.replace("u", " ");
let wordThree = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
let inputThree = wordThree
.replace("ó", " ")
.replace("u", " ");
let wordFour = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
let inputFour = wordFour
.replace("ó", " ")
.replace("u", " ");
let randomWord = `${inputOne}, ${inputTwo}, ${inputThree}, ${inputFour}`;

word1Element.innerHTML = inputOne;
word2Element.innerHTML = inputTwo;
word3Element.innerHTML = inputThree;
word4Element.innerHTML = inputFour;
return randomWord;
};

startButton.onclick = randomWords;
```

Im writing a program which draw random letter from an array, and hide specific letters. Those hidden letters should be visible as input fields. I manage to create HTML with input fields, used replace method in js to replace those letters with empty space. I have no idea how to replace those empty spaces with input fields. So user can input correct letter and than check their grammar by that.

By creating HTML, CSS and JS, I manage to draw properly 4 words with blank spaces in place of specific letters. Whenever I try to add input field into those empty spaces it just does't work at all. Input fields are visible, but their are position accordingly to words, as written in css.

Comment: If you are using `innerHTML` anyway, can't you just use `<input>` instead of `" "`?

Comment: Yes, that works. I need to use input variables from top of my js code. I'm struggling for 2 days with that. Can't find any solution which will direct me on how to achieve that. Any idea?

Comment: To be specific, I want to use `input1Element` to replace those specific letters inside `word1Element`. And so on with the rest of the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `.replace(/[óu]/g, "<input>")` is what you need

`/[óu]/g` is a regular expression that matches `ó` or `u`

```js
const word1Element = document.getElementById("word1");

let result;

function randomWords() {
  word1Element.style.display = "block";
  const words = [
    "kółko", "muzyka", "odór", "kukułka", "lupa", "buk", "półka", "kufel", "kultura", "chór",
    "muzeum", "rura", "kukułka", "róg", "lufa", "łuk", "łosoś", "kurtka", "budynek",
    "kukułka", "suknia", "ucho", "gorąco", "bułka", "szukanie", "podróż", "góra", "usta",
    "bukiet", "klucz", "łuk", "okrągły", "ludzie", "bułka", "kruk", "król", "żuraw", "kubek",
    "bukiet", "mówić", "płótno", "ludność", "kuracja", "kutia", "ubranie", "ukośny", "bukiet",
    "bruk", "kultura", "ruch", "buda", "kurczak", "dusza", "łuk", "kupować", "trudność", "brud",
    "skurczybyk", "słońce", "lód", "kupa", "lukier", "brud", "kusza", "tłum", "kufel", "duma",
    "kupa", "pukanie", "kuracja", "burza", "kurtka", "smród", "bułka", "mur", "kultura", "buzia",
    "kurczak", "kąt", "żurawina", "łuk", "kula", "ukośny", "bukiet", "turysta", "urodziny",
    "kufel", "buzia", "młodzież", "kuferek", "bujny", "ucieczka", "kuracja", "kutia", "rzut",
    "bukiet", "wulkan", "kucyk", "uśmiech"
  ];
  let wordOne = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
  let inputOne = wordOne
    .replace(/[óu]/g, "<input>")

  let randomWord = `${inputOne}`;

  word1Element.innerHTML = inputOne;
  return randomWord;
};

randomWords()
```

```css
input {
  width: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<p id="word1"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer does the job and solve my problem. But the thing is, how can I use input fields which are already declared in my js file and html. I need to use those specific input fields as I want later on pass each field to check if user manage to answer correctly and if answers match words. So my question is, how to add my input field variables so they replace those letters. I need to use those specific declared input fields...

Comment: @Fresh please accept the answer then, the grey checkbox